# NSEntityDescription is nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

My variable `entityDescription` seems to be nil, so I have a fatal error while compiling. Does anyone knows a solution? `persistentContainer` is declared in the same class (AppDelegate).

```
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: self.persistentContainer.viewContext)
let newPerson = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: self.persistentContainer.viewContext)
newPerson.setValue("Thomas", forKey: "first")
```

Answer (score 4):

Please check the method name, The following code creates a NSEntityDescription object for me.

```
let desc:NSEntityDescription? = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext);
print(desc)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the Core Data Xcode template. (Choose new project, check, Master/Detail, check Core Data.) In Swift 3 you would create a new object like by using a valid managed object context.

```
let newPerson = Person(context: context)
newPerson.first = "Thomas"
```

Comment: This is only available for iOS 10, for versions below that you should check Arun EA 's response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38344166/2452039

Comment: No, the API syntax is different, the principle is the same in previous versions of Core Data many years back.